# How to fix the error name 'phi' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, jupyter-notebook, symbolic-math

I'm trying to solve the following laplace transform: f(t) = sen(ωt + φ)
I wrote the following code to solve the problem

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import s,t,x,y,z
from sympy.integrals import laplace_transform 
from sympy.integrals import inverse_laplace_transform
omega = sympy.Symbol('omega', real=True)
sin = sympy.sin
function = (sin(omega*t + phi))
function
U = laplace_transform(function, t, s)
U[0]
```

As you can see, I tried the code above to solve the problem, however, the error that the name 'phi' is not defined. Could someone give me an idea of ​​what I would have to fix to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried defining it like this? `phi = sympy.Symbol('phi', real=True)`

Comment: What is `phi`? You get the error because you _haven't_ defined it, only you know what it needs to be so define it!

Comment: why `import sympy as sym` if you're going to reference it like `sympy.Symbol` instead of `sym.Symbol`? Why `sin = sympy.sin` instead of `from sympy import sin`? What are omega and phi supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a import for phi

```
from sympy.abc import phi
```